# unity c# - how to get values of list<object>

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, mono

I have this json:

> ```
> [
>   [
>     [
>       "Tel Aviv",
>       "Beersheba",
>       "Jerusalem",
>       "Haifa"
>     ]
>   ],
>   [
>     {
>       "City": "Tel Aviv"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Beersheba"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Jerusalem"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Haifa"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Jerusalem"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Tel Aviv"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Haifa"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Beersheba"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Jerusalem"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Jerusalem"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Haifa"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Tel Aviv"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Tel Aviv"
>     },
>     {
>       "City": "Beersheba"
>     }
>   ]
> ]
> ```

And i converted it to a List:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft;
string jsonStr = "<json string from above>";
List<object> data;
private void Start()
{
    data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(jsonStr);
    Debug.Log(data[0,0]);
}
```

But when the dubugger got to "Debug.Log(data[0,0]);" it printed:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\cdi2\Downloads\mdClone-20180627T083334Z-001\mdClone\Assets\CreateTable.cs  31  Active

Comment: And what do you expect it to print?

Comment: the first value: "Tel Aviv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is deserialized in a `List<object>` A list can be indexed with only one dimension.
So the deserialization creates only two objects of type JArray.
The first one is the group of four cities and the second one is an array of 14 cities.

You can get the first element of the first object with

```
Console.WriteLine((data[0] as JArray)[0][0]);
```

While, if you want to reach any of the elements in the second JArray you can use this syntax

```
Console.WriteLine((data[1] as JArray)[1]["City"]);   // Beersheba
```